# Problem to load data from folder using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have XLS worksheet file with title 'STOP_REPORT_TEST_2012' and my code file (ipynb) also in same folder.
When I try to load data in my notebook it gave this FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'STOP_REPORT_TEST_2012.csv':

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('STOP_REPORT_TEST_2012.csv')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-482e5950774f> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv('STOP_REPORT_TEST_2012.csv')

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    608     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    609 
--> 610     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    611 
    612 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    460 
    461     # Create the parser.
--> 462     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    463 
    464     if chunksize or iterator:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    817             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    818 
--> 819         self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
    820 
    821     def close(self):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1048             )
   1049         # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
-> 1050         return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
   1051 
   1052     def _failover_to_python(self):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1865 
   1866         # open handles
-> 1867         self._open_handles(src, kwds)
   1868         assert self.handles is not None
   1869         for key in ("storage_options", "encoding", "memory_map", "compression"):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _open_handles(self, src, kwds)
   1360         Let the readers open IOHanldes after they are done with their potential raises.
   1361         """
-> 1362         self.handles = get_handle(
   1363             src,
   1364             "r",

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    645                 errors = "replace"
    646             # Encoding
--> 647             handle = open(
    648                 handle,
    649                 ioargs.mode,

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'STOP_REPORT_TEST_2012.csv'
```

I also try

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'STOP_REPORT_TEST_2012.csv')
```

Still have same error.How to fix this?

Comment: Hi can you try this, And kindly post your folder structure. <br/>
```df = pd.read_csv('./STOP_REPORT_TEST_2012.csv')```

Comment: If it is a XLS worksheet, shouldn't the file extension be `xlsx` and shouldn't you use `load_excel` than `load_csv`

Answer (score 0):

first you need to find the dir for your notebook than modify the dir for the file

```
 import os
 os.getcwd()
```

Comment: I've checked dir for both notebook and file. they were in the same location:
{import os

cwd = os.getcwd() 
print("Current working directory:", cwd)
Current working directory: C:\Users\NITRO 5\Desktop\Python machine learning & data science}

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully I've found the answer. @heretolearn was right. I need to install xlrd `pip install xlrd` then read the data using
`pd.read_excel('STOP_REPORT_TEST_2012.xls')`